# order by with a case expression

Tags: sql, sqlite, case-expression

I have a complex `order by` with `case` expression.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field_1 = ? then 0 
              WHEN field_2 = ? then 1 ELSE 3 end ASC
```

i want to order the inner results by a `field_3`

for example my table is -

```
index | field_1 | field_2 | field_3
  0   |   car   |  red    |   2
  1   |   hat   |  red    |   5
  2   |   red   |  house  |   4
```

and `? = red`

So index 0 and 1 will get 1 and index 2 will get 0 from the case expression.

and i want to order again by `field_3` but the order should only be between the values that are the same.

so index 0,1 should `order by field_3`

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

---

The result should be -

index 2 -> index 0 -> index 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand but why not just do

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field_1 = ? then 0 
              WHEN field_2 = ? then 1 ELSE 3 end ASC, field_3 ASC
```

If the first part (the CASE) are equal for two or more rows then those rows will be sorted by `field_3`

Comment: I added a result for the example.

Comment: will this order the end result by field_3? or only the results that are the same like index 1,2?

Comment: Only when the results are the same

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `field_3` also inside the case statement at the else part:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN field_1 = 'red' then -2 
    WHEN field_2 = 'red' then -1 
    ELSE field_3 
  END, field_3
```

I used negative values just in case `0` or `1` are possible values in the `field_3` column.